Thai word not breaking properly between lines, in LuaLaTeX
I am currently writing lecture notes in Thai based on the code I got from previous questions asked here: Setting multiple language environments in LaTeX .
Here's the MWE:
%&------- Based on Davislor's proposal code, using LuaLaTeX to compile ---------&
\documentclass[b5paper]{article}
\tracinglostchars=3 
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\babelprovide[import, main, onchar=fonts ids]{thai}
\babelprovide[import, onchar=fonts ids]{english}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase, Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont[Scale=1,%
ItalicFont=NewCM10-Italic.otf,%
BoldFont=NewCM10-Bold.otf,%
BoldItalicFont=NewCM10-BoldItalic.otf,%
SmallCapsFeatures={Numbers=OldStyle}]{NewCM10-Regular.otf}

\babelfont[thai]{rm}
          [Scale=1.15]{TH Sarabun Chula}
\setmathfont{NewCMMath-Regular.otf}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left=1.0in,
            right=1.0in,
            top=1.0in,
            bottom=1.0in}

\begin{document}
    {\Large{\textbf{แบบฝึกหัด การประมาณ}}}
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item ในการศึกษาการเจริญเติบโตของทารกอายุ 1 เดือนว่ามีน้ำหนักเพิ่มขึ้นจากแรกคลอดอยู่ในช่วงใด ผู้ทำการศึกษาได้สุ่มตัวอย่างขนาด 100 ซึ่งให้ค่าเฉลี่ยเลขคณิตและส่วนเบี่ยงเบนมาตรฐานของน้ำหนักที่เพิ่มขึ้นจากแรกคลอดเป็น 980 กรัม และ 60 กรัมตามลำดับ ถ้าน้ำหนักที่เพิ่มขึ้นของทารกอายุ 1 เดือนมีการแจกแจงปกติ จงหาความเชื่อมั่น 96\% ของค่าเฉลี่ยของน้ำหนักที่เพิ่มขึ้นจากแรกคลอดของประชากรทารกอายุ 1 เดือน
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}

And this is the result I got after compling with LuaLaTeX:

The words I circle in blue, "ศึก" and "ษา", were supposed to be a single word written together, as in "ศึกษา". But what I got is seperated syllables, which happens when a long word reaches the end of each line. This dissatisfies me throughout the writing process.
Is there any way to fix this issue in particular, or at least hyphenate the syllables?
Thank you in advance.
EDIT: If wanted, here's the link to download the TH Sarabun Chula font: https://www.arts.chula.ac.th/ling/sdm_downloads/th-sarabun-chula/
Scroll down until you see the green button and click to download.
EDIT2: Added geometry package and page margin settings.

Hello, your method works! However, what I want is to merge these syllables without manually typing the \mbox{}. That would be really tiring to type that throughout the pages haha. Are there any efficient ways to do so? Thank you.

Yes, that is better.

I use TeXworks. Maybe this happens because of the editor I use?

You can compare your log with this project on overleaf which gets the same linebreaking as my local installation https://www.overleaf.com/read/htvcwbkqcfzs#db6e1d

The only change I made was to load the font via its .ttf file name as it was a local file I had just downloaded from your link.

I've looked into your code and compared to mine. I realized what makes your display different from mine is that I forgot to put my page margin settings. Here, I'll put them in my MWE.

grr you should always post the output from the posted code not some other document:-), I get same as you now

You can add patterns with \babelpatterns to prevent (or to allow) ‘hyphenation’ points (in this case, linebreaking points). For this particular combination, write in the preamble:
\babelpatterns{ศึก2ษา}

It seems 2 is enough, but 4, 6, and 8 also work.
Don’t box this character group. Thai justification will be wrong.

thanks, I deleted mine :-)

@DavidCarlisle A few languages (eg, Thai and Amharic) segment text with hyphenation patterns. Then babel post-processes discretionaries to get the correct output.

I get the same problem as you have. But if I didn't use the babel setting
and instead \setmainfont  I get another linebreak:
%\babelfont[thai]{rm}%
\setmainfont[Scale=1.15]{THSarabunChula-Regular.ttf}



This doesn’t solve the original issue. Of course, if the font setup is different, line break will be also different.

so what does \babelfont  in difference to fontspec??

Sets the Language and the Script font features, and, in this particular example (because of onchar=ids fonts),  switches automatically the font depending on the script.
